# How to create enum with both string and int (string) values

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, enums

I need to check some conditions which are string values can be like "12234", "12345", "54321", "testValue"
I want to create an enum with these values and try parsing enum values on my if condition, but can we create enum with both string and int values like below?

Other option would be array but I want to check if we can create a enum or not.

```
public enum test
{
    12234,12345,54321,testValue
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a misuse of enums and an XY problem, why do you need this? Alternative you could use an attribute, store you data in that, and use reflection to query it and help return the enum. You could also use a dictionary i suppose, and map to an enum, or just a good old fashioned switch with constants

Comment: Enum names can only start with an alphabet. you can assign these numbers to the names but not numbers as names. This is not a valid way to instantiate an enum class.

Comment: No Strings: An enumeration type (or enum type) is a value type defined by a set of named constants of the underlying integral numeric type.

Comment: I am not sure what the goal is here, but you could do something like this: public enum test
{
    NUM_12234,NUM_12345,NUM_54321,testValue
} However, in this case testValue isn't a string, it is a name for an integer.

Comment: Hi Roshan, following up to check if the answer below helped clarified your ask in the post, if it is not completely answered you can share your doubts and I'll try to clarify them ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Enums must be of the integral numeric type, so you can't have strings as Enum constants*

**An Example Of Enum below**

```
 enum TestConditions
 {
   One = 12234,
   Two = 12345,
   Three=54321,

 }

 //Enum 

 Console.WriteLine((int)TestConditions.One); //Output = 12234
 Console.WriteLine(TestConditions.One); //Output = One
 Console.WriteLine((TestConditions)12234); // Output = One
```

*Perhaps you could you use a static class like this*

```
 public static class TestCondition
 {

      public static string One = "12234";
      public static string Two = "12345";
      public static int Three = 54321;

 }
```